# pyenv cannot install python >=3.0.1<3.5

Tags: python, pyenv

Log is so big, need to search through it:
https://logpaste.com/EI9T2T7e

i tried to install every module that was listed still no luck. FYI i could install 2.7.17 and 3.6.9 with

```
sudo apt install gcc-10
CC=gcc-10 pyenv install 3.6.9
```

some of the logs for better search:

```
(cd /home/meretricula/.pyenv/versions/3.4.10/bin; ln -s pyvenv-3.4 pyvenv)
if test "x" != "x" ; then \
    rm -f /home/meretricula/.pyenv/versions/3.4.10/bin/python3-32; \
    (cd /home/meretricula/.pyenv/versions/3.4.10/bin; ln -s python3.4-32 python3-32) \
fi
rm -f /home/meretricula/.pyenv/versions/3.4.10/share/man/man1/python3.1
(cd /home/meretricula/.pyenv/versions/3.4.10/share/man/man1; ln -s python3.4.1 python3.1)
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
    case upgrade in \
        upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
        install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
    esac; \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/python-build.20230810133615.387520/Python-3.4.10 ./python -E -m ensurepip \
        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 9.0.1 requires SSL/TLS
/home/meretricula/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/bin/python-build: line 1805: 401343 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) "$PYTHON_BIN" -c "import $1"
WARNING: The Python ctypes extension was not compiled. Missing the libffi lib?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/meretricula/.pyenv/versions/3.4.10/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 97, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named '_ssl'
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (Linuxmint 21.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20230810133615.387520
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20230810133615.387520.log

Last 10 log lines:
(cd /home/meretricula/.pyenv/versions/3.4.10/share/man/man1; ln -s python3.4.1 python3.1)
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
    case upgrade in \
        upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
        install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
    esac; \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/python-build.20230810133615.387520/Python-3.4.10 ./python -E -m ensurepip \
        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 9.0.1 requires SSL/TLS
```

Comment: In 2023, there is no good reason to install such an old python version. Python 2.7 and 3.4 have been end of life for 4 years.

Check https://endoflife.date/python for the currently supported versions.

Comment: i need it for work i need a version that is as the title says. some of the repositories use old python version

Comment: i actually misread the requirements for python, so this is no longer needed for my work... however someone may have a need to install such an old python which are problematic to install my guess is that ssl which is used by the system is 1.1 but these versions listed need 1.0 which i found on the common-buil-problems wiki 
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems
i wasnt able to fix it.